# Monero wallet balance

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I have a monero-gui wallet: it shows my XMR balance, which is not zero.  When I open monero-wallet.cli it shows my balance is 0.000. What is going on here?

Comment: Both were created from the same seed?  Both have a daemon running? Both have refreshed through the same (latest) block?

Answer (score 1):

This look like you have a balance on subaddresses but not on main address.
While the GUI aggregates all accounts addresses in a single balance, the CLI does not.

You could do a `show_balance all` on the CLI (IIRC) and check if the balance is on one or many subaddresses.